# How to strip a special character from multiple columns at once in python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to strip a special character from all columns in a data frame at the same time. it seems to work when using the iloc function on a single columns but when I try to use select multiple columns it doesn't seem to work.

```
df.iloc[:,1:10] = df.iloc[:,1:10].str.strip('%')
```

Comment: did you try `df.replace('%','',regex=True)`?

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just curious why the iloc with the strip not work?